# How to pass array inputs as parameter to async function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, function, async-await

I got set of urls from txt file [which I am having in my local] which I got as array inputs with below code

```
fs.readFile('urls.txt', function(err, data) {
    if(err) throw err;
    var testurls = data.toString().split("\n");  
});
```

Sample output when I do console.log(testurls)
[
'https://sample1.com'
'https://sample2.com'
]

How to pass the values to below function as parameter/argument to run scan on each url one after other as I am trying to  some performance test using light house?

```
async function nav_to_site() {
    const home_url = testurls;
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: true,
        defaultViewport: null,
        executablePath: '/usr/local/bin/chromium',
        args: ['--headless', '--no-sandbox', '--remote-debugging-port=9222', '--disable-gpu'],
    });

(async () => {
    let browser = null;
    let page = null;

    try {
        browser = await nav_to_site();
        console.log('Running lighthouse...');
        page = (await browser.pages())[0];
        const report = await lighthouse(page.url(), {
            port: 9222,
            output: 'json',
            logLevel: 'info',
            disableDeviceEmulation: true,
            budgetPath: 'budget.json',
            chromeFlags: ['--disable-gpu', '--no-sandbox', '--disable-storage-reset']
        }, config);
        const json = reportGenerator.generateReport(report.lhr, 'json');
        const html = reportGenerator.generateReport(report.lhr, 'html');

}
```

Comment: You should [edit] your question, or ask another, if an answer doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy way?  Use `fs.readFileSync()` to load that text file.

Harder way, but better if the file is large? Promisify the reading of the file so you can call it with `await`.  Then use a loop to do your puppeteer thing.

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const util = require('util');
const readFile = util.promisify(fs.readFile);

async function getUrlsFromFile {
  const contents = await readFile('urls.txt');
  return lines.toString().split('\n')
}

async function nav_to_all_sites_one_by_one() {
    testurls = await getUrlsFromFile()
    /* avoid forEach here */
    for (let testurl of testurls) {
      const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: true,
        defaultViewport: null,
        executablePath: '/usr/local/bin/chromium',
        args: ['--headless', '--no-sandbox', '--remote-debugging-port=9222', '--disable-gpu'],
      });

      console.log('Running lighthouse on', testurl);
      page = (await browser.pages())[0];
      const report = await lighthouse(page.url(), {
            port: 9222,
            output: 'json',
            logLevel: 'info',
            disableDeviceEmulation: true,
            budgetPath: 'budget.json',
            chromeFlags: ['--disable-gpu', '--no-sandbox', '--disable-storage-reset']
        }, config);
      const json = reportGenerator.generateReport(report.lhr, 'json');
      const html = reportGenerator.generateReport(report.lhr, 'html');
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello Jones,
Tried to use the above code and got below error

UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: LHError: INVALID_URL error while executing the above code.

Is this not reading the url content with https correctly from urls.txt file?
Kindly help